# Segmentation fault in C using arrow operator

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm still fairly new to C, so I'm missing a few things in my knowledge.
I keep getting a segmentation fault at:
`s->num= -1;`
and I simply cannot figure it out, so I'm hoping someone here can.

```
typedef struct {
  char data[MAX_STR];
  int  x;
  int  list[MAX_LIST];
} Delta;

typedef struct {
  int top;
  Delta d[MAX_DELTA];
} Stack;

void initer(Stack*s)
{
    Delta *newArray;
    newArray = (Delta *)malloc(sizeof(Delta)* MAX_ARR_SIZE);
    memcpy(newArray, s->d, sizeof(char)*MAX_ARR_SIZE);
    s->top= -1; 
}
```

Comment: How do you call `initer()`?

Comment: Thanks, you asking me that actually helped me figure it out. Stack s wasn't initialized yet, so I set I made a new Stack and set its address to s.

Comment: You're copying MAX_ARR_SIZE bytes, and allocating `MAX_ARR_SIZE` elements for newArray... but you've made `d` `MAX_DELTA` elements long... do they match?

Comment: Don't cast the return of malloc().

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: And do not cast the rsult of `malloc` & friends in C! If your compiler complains, you are using a C++ compiler: **do not!**.

Comment: `sizeof(Delta)* MAX_ARR_SIZE` is *not equal* to `sizeof(char)*MAX_ARR_SIZE`, so you're copying less than you're allocating.  And `Stack::d` is `MAX_DELTA * sizeof(Delta)` bytes long, which may or may not be right depending on what `MAX_DELTA` is... but even if it's the right value, why use both `MAX_DELTA` and `MAX_ARR_SIZE` for the same measure when that makes it not obvious whether the sizes match?

Comment: Better delete this question as the code is incomplete and does not have an [mcve]

Comment: Also, what happens to `newArray`?  Looks like it just goes out of scope at the end of the function so the copy is useless and you leak memory... or is there missing code?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but figured it out. Stack s wasn't initialized yet, so I set I made a new Stack and set its address to s.